# Javascript multi statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, range

I am building little app with JS and I find difficult with that:

I want to get from users input an integer number from range 0-100. If it's not an int I am parsing it to int. Then I want to put that number to function checkNum, and there appears a problem.
Let me paste my code:

```
$(function () {

initApp();

function getInput(){
    var userInput = window.prompt("Input number from range 0-100");
    var num = parseInt(userInput);
    return num;
};


function checkInput(num){
    if( num < 0 || num > 100){
        displayError();
    }
    else{
        alert('num is ok');
    }
};

function displayError(){
  alert("error");
};

function initApp(){
    getInput();
    checkInput();
};
```

});

As you can see even if I put number out of range there is always alert says num is ok - what is not true. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I'll appreciate any help. What is more, I'd like to put here function Number.isNaN() to provide typing non-sense in the input. I thought about statement like this:

```
if(Number.isNaN(num) || num <0 || num > 100){...}
```

I guess that my mistake is obvious and trivial for someone more experienced than me.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but should always explicitly set the second parameter of `parseInt()`: `parseInt(userInput, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you're passing nothing to `checkInput()` so it's always undefined, and `undefined < 0 || undefined > 100` is always false. The solution is to pass the returned value from `getInput()` to `checkInput()` like so:

```
function initApp(){
    var value = getInput();
    checkInput(value);
}
```

---

To answer what you're aiming for: use `<input type="number">` and have the browser do the work for you.

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
  <button>Try to submit!</button>
</form>
```

No JavaScript required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the return value from `getInput` into `checkInput`:

```
function initApp(){
    checkInput(getInput());
}
```

Side note: Function *declarations* (what you've used) don't need `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the value returned by getInput like this ;)

```js
initApp();

function getInput(){
    var userInput = window.prompt("Input number from range 0-100");
    var num = parseInt(userInput);
    return num;
};


function checkInput(num){
    if( num < 0 || num > 100){
        displayError();
    }
    else{
        alert('num is ok');
    }
};

function displayError(){
  alert("error");
};

function initApp(){
    var value = getInput();
    checkInput(value);
};
```